# Unexpected maxima value

Tags: calculus

When I was plotting random graphs, I came across this graph that was funny looking, but I realised that the maxima occur when x is the golden ratio. This was very interesting to me but I could not prove that the golden ratio is the maxima and I am very confused.

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the logarithm to simplify things. So you want to maximize

$$
\log(x-1)-\log x-x\;.
$$

Setting the derivative with respect to $x$ to $0$ yields

$$
\frac1{x-1}-\frac1x-1=0\;,
$$

and this leads to the quadratic equation for the golden ratio, $x^2-x-1=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac {x-1}{x\,e^x}\implies f'(x)=-\frac{ \left(x^2-x-1\right)}{x^2\,e^x}$$ Make it equal to $0$ and perform the second derivative test to confirm that it is a maximum.